# ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). SciPy.integrare and odient

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I'm solving a series of 80 ODE's that represent the dynamics of an influenza outbreak in a population split into three immunity levels and four age groups. I have just changed my initial conditions to account for some people to be asymptomatic. And now have an error message. My initial conditions are now:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
# N is the sum of all the age compartments

N1 = 8010000
N2 = 7610000
N3 = 38810000
N4 = 12390000
N = N1 + N2 + N3 + N4

# Initial number of all compartment

# Exposed

E_s10 = 0
E_s20 = 0
E_s30 = 0
E_s40 = 0

E_v10 = 0
E_v20 = 0
E_v30 = 0
E_v40 = 0

E_i10 = 0
E_i20 = 0
E_i30 = 0
E_i40 = 0
#Symptomatic Infections 

I_s10 = 29700
I_s20 = 27225
I_s30 = 143550
I_s40 = 47025

I_v10 = 0
I_v20 = 0
I_v30 = 0
I_v40 = 0

I_i10 = 0
I_i20 = 0
I_i30 = 0
I_i40 = 0

#Asymptomatic Infections 

A_s10 = 9900
A_s20 = 9075
A_s30 = 47850
A_s40 = 15675

A_v10 = 0
A_v20 = 0
A_v30 = 0
A_v40 = 0

A_i10 = 0
A_i20 = 0
A_i30 = 0
A_i40 = 0
#Recovered 

R_s10 = 0
R_s20 = 0
R_s30 = 0
R_s40 = 0

R_v10 = 0
R_v20 = 0
R_v30 = 0
R_v40 = 0

R_i10 = 0
R_i20 = 0
R_i30 = 0
R_i40 = 0

# Susceptibles 
V10 = 0
V20 = 0
V30 = 0
V40 = 0

S_i10 = 3188160
S_i20 = 3029480
S_i30 = 15447440
S_i40 = 4930920

S10 = (N1 - V10 - S_i10 - E_s10 - E_v10 - E_i10 - I_s10 - I_v10 - I_i10 - A_s10 - A_v10 - A_i10 - R_s10 - R_v10 - R_i10) * 0.6
S20 = (N2 - V20 - S_i20 - E_s20 - E_v20 - E_i20 - I_s20 - I_v20 - I_i20 - A_s20 - A_v20 - A_i20 - R_s20 - R_v20 - R_i20) * 0.6
S30 = (N3 - V30 - S_i30 - E_s30 - E_v30 - E_i30 - I_s30 - I_v30 - I_i30 - A_s30 - A_v30 - A_i30 - R_s30 - R_v30 - R_i30) * 0.6
S40 = (N4 - V40 - S_i40 - E_s40 - E_v40 - E_i40 - I_s40 - I_v40 - I_i40 - A_s40 - A_v40 - A_i40 - R_s40 - R_v40 - R_i40) * 0.6

#Cummulative Innitial Conditions
C_s10 = 0
C_s20 = 0
C_s30 = 0
C_s40 = 0
C_v10 = 0
C_v20 = 0
C_v30 = 0
C_v40 = 0
C_i10 = 0
C_i20 = 0
C_i30 = 0
C_i40 = 0
C_s0 = 0
C_v0 = 0
C_i0 = 0
C0 = 0

# Vaccination profile 
V_overall10 = 0 
V_overall20 = 0
V_overall30 = 0
V_overall40 = 0

# Definitions of parameters
m = 0.5
# Contact Rates
beta11 = 0.98
beta12 = 0.25 * m 
beta13 = 1.1 * m
beta14 = 0.096 * m
beta21 = 0.22
beta22 = 1.5 * m
beta23 = 1.1 * m
beta24 = 0.15 * m
beta31 = 0.21
beta32 = 0.24 * m
beta33 = 1.5 * m
beta34 = 0.2 * m
beta41 = 0.069
beta42 = 0.12 * m
beta43 = 0.74 * m
beta44 = 0.36 * m

kappa = 0.71
alpha = 0.26
eta = 0.26
delta_i = 1
delta_v = 1
delta_a = 0.2
s_i = 0.3
p = 0.75
q = 0.25
l = 0.2

#Vaccine Efficacy
s_v1 = 0.48
s_v2 = 0.07
s_v3 = 0.20
s_v4 = 0.12

def epsilon1(t, V1, E_v1, I_v1, A_v1, R_v1, N1):
    if V1 + E_v1 + I_v1 + A_v1 + R_v1 > 0.4 * N1:
        return 0
    elif 0 < t <= 28:
        return 0 
    elif 28 < t <= 84:
        return 0.006 * N1 / (N1 - (V1 + E_v1 + I_v1 + A_v1 + R_v1))
    elif 84 < t <= 105:
        return 0.001 * N1 / (N1 - (V1 + E_v1 + I_v1 + A_v1 + R_v1))
    else:
        return 0 

def epsilon2(t, V2, E_v2, I_v2, A_v2, R_v2, N2):
    return 0.004 * N2 / (N2 - (V2 + E_v2 + I_v2 + A_v2 + R_v2)) if V2 + E_v2 + I_v2 + A_v2 + R_v2 < 0.4 * N2 else 0

def epsilon3(t, V3, E_v3, I_v3, A_v3, R_v3, N3):
        return 0.004 * N3 / (N3 - (V3 + E_v3 + I_v3 + A_v3 + R_v3)) if V3 + E_v3 + I_v3 + A_v3 + R_v3 < 0.4 * N3 else 0

def epsilon4(t, V4, E_v4, I_v4, A_v4, R_v4, N4):
    if V4 + E_v4 + I_v4 + A_v4 + R_v4 > 0.714 * N4:
        return 0
    elif t <= 49:
        return 0.01 * N4 / (N4 - (V4 + E_v4 + I_v4 + A_v4 + R_v4))
    elif 49 < t <= 105:
        return 0.001 * N4 / (N4 - (V4 + E_v4 + I_v4 + A_v4 + R_v4))
    else:
        return 0

# A grid of time points (in days)
t = np.linspace(0, 300, 300)

# The SIR model differential equations.
def deriv(y, t, N, beta11, beta12, beta13, beta14, beta21, beta22, beta23, beta24, beta31, beta32, beta33, beta34, beta41, beta42, beta43, beta44, kappa, alpha, epsilon1, epsilon2, epsilon3, epsilon4, eta,  delta_i, delta_v, delta_a, s_i, s_v1, s_v2, s_v3, s_v4, p, q, l):
S1, S2, S3, S4, V1, V2, V3, V4, S_i1, S_i2, S_i3, S_i4, E_s1, E_s2, E_s3, E_s4, E_v1, E_v2, E_v3, E_v4, E_i1, E_i2, E_i3, E_i4, I_s1, I_s2, I_s3, I_s4, I_v1, I_v2, I_v3, I_v4, I_i1, I_i2, I_i3, I_i4, A_s1, A_s2, A_s3, A_s4, A_v1, A_v2, A_v3, A_v4, A_i1, A_i2, A_i3, A_i4, R_s1, R_s2, R_s3, R_s4, R_v1, R_v2, R_v3, R_v4, R_i1, R_i2, R_i3, R_i4, C_s1, C_s2, C_s3, C_s4, C_i1, C_i2, C_i3, C_i4, C_v1, C_v2, C_v3, C_v4, C_s, C_v, C_i, C, dV_overall1dt, dV_overall2dt, dV_overall3dt, dV_overall4dt = y
Lambda1 = beta11 * (I_s1 + delta_a * A_s1 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v1 + delta_v * I_v1 + delta_i * I_i1 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i1)/N1 + beta12 * (I_s2 + delta_a * A_s2 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v2 + delta_v * I_v2 + delta_i * I_i2 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i2)/N2 + beta13 * (I_s3 + delta_a * A_s3 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v3 + delta_v * I_v3 + delta_i * I_i3 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i3)/N3 + beta14 * (I_s4 + delta_a * A_s4 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v4 + delta_v * I_v4 + delta_i * I_i4 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i4)/N4
Lambda2 = beta21 * (I_s1 + delta_a * A_s1 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v1 + delta_v * I_v1 + delta_i * I_i1 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i1)/N1 + beta22 * (I_s2 + delta_a * A_s2 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v2 + delta_v * I_v2 + delta_i * I_i2 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i2)/N2 + beta23 * (I_s3 + delta_a * A_s3 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v3 + delta_v * I_v3 + delta_i * I_i3 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i3)/N3 + beta24 * (I_s4 + delta_a * A_s4 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v4 + delta_v * I_v4 + delta_i * I_i4 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i4)/N4
Lambda3 = beta31 * (I_s1 + delta_a * A_s1 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v1 + delta_v * I_v1 + delta_i * I_i1 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i1)/N1 + beta32 * (I_s2 + delta_a * A_s2 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v2 + delta_v * I_v2 + delta_i * I_i2 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i2)/N2 + beta33 * (I_s3 + delta_a * A_s3 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v3 + delta_v * I_v3 + delta_i * I_i3 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i3)/N3 + beta34 * (I_s4 + delta_a * A_s4 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v4 + delta_v * I_v4 + delta_i * I_i4 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i4)/N4
Lambda4 = beta41 * (I_s1 + delta_a * A_s1 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v1 + delta_v * I_v1 + delta_i * I_i1 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i1)/N1 + beta42 * (I_s2 + delta_a * A_s2 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v2 + delta_v * I_v2 + delta_i * I_i2 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i2)/N2 + beta43 * (I_s3 + delta_a * A_s3 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v3 + delta_v * I_v3 + delta_i * I_i3 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i3)/N3 + beta44 * (I_s4 + delta_a * A_s4 + delta_v * delta_a * A_v4 + delta_v * I_v4 + delta_i * I_i4 + delta_a * delta_i * A_i4)/N4
epsilon_current1 = epsilon1(t, V1, E_v1, I_v1, A_v1, R_v1, N1)
epsilon_current2 = epsilon2(t, V2, E_v2, I_v2, A_v2, R_v2, N2)
epsilon_current3 = epsilon3(t, V3, E_v3, I_v3, A_v3, R_v3, N3)
epsilon_current4 = epsilon4(t, V4, E_v4, I_v4, A_v4, R_v4, N4)
dS1dt = - Lambda1 * S1 - epsilon_current1 * S1
dS2dt = - Lambda2 * S2 - epsilon_current2 * S2 
dS3dt = - Lambda3 * S3 - epsilon_current3 * S3 
dS4dt = - Lambda4 * S4 - epsilon_current4 * S4
dV1dt = epsilon_current1 * S1 + epsilon_current1 * S_i1 - s_v1 * Lambda1 * V1
dV2dt = epsilon_current2 * S2 + epsilon_current2 * S_i2 - s_v2 * Lambda2 * V2
dV3dt = epsilon_current3 * S3 + epsilon_current3 * S_i3 - s_v3 * Lambda3 * V3
dV4dt = epsilon_current4 * S4 + epsilon_current4 * S_i4 - s_v4 * Lambda4 * V4
dS_i1dt = -s_i * Lambda1 * S_i1 - epsilon_current1 * S_i1
dS_i2dt = -s_i * Lambda2 * S_i2 - epsilon_current2 * S_i2
dS_i3dt = -s_i * Lambda3 * S_i3 - epsilon_current3 * S_i3
dS_i4dt = -s_i * Lambda4 * S_i4 - epsilon_current4 * S_i4
dE_s1dt = Lambda1 * S1 - kappa * E_s1 - epsilon_current1 * E_s1
dE_s2dt = Lambda2 * S2 - kappa * E_s2 - epsilon_current2 * E_s2
dE_s3dt = Lambda3 * S3 - kappa * E_s3 - epsilon_current3 * E_s3
dE_s4dt = Lambda4 * S4 - kappa * E_s4 - epsilon_current4 * E_s4
dE_v1dt = s_v1 * Lambda1 * V1 - kappa * E_v1 + epsilon_current1 * E_s1 + epsilon_current1 * E_i1
dE_v2dt = s_v2 * Lambda2 * V2 - kappa * E_v2 + epsilon_current2 * E_s2 + epsilon_current2 * E_i2
dE_v3dt = s_v3 * Lambda3 * V3 - kappa * E_v3 + epsilon_current3 * E_s3 + epsilon_current3 * E_i3
dE_v4dt = s_v4 * Lambda4 * V4 - kappa * E_v4 + epsilon_current4 * E_s4 + epsilon_current4 * E_i4
dE_i1dt = s_i * Lambda1 * S_i1 - kappa * E_i1 - epsilon_current1 * E_i1
dE_i2dt = s_i * Lambda2 * S_i2 - kappa * E_i2 - epsilon_current2 * E_i2
dE_i3dt = s_i * Lambda3 * S_i3 - kappa * E_i3 - epsilon_current3 * E_i3
dE_i4dt = s_i * Lambda4 * S_i4 - kappa * E_i4 - epsilon_current4 * E_i4
dI_s1dt = p * kappa * E_s1 - alpha * I_s1
dI_s2dt = p * kappa * E_s2 - alpha * I_s2
dI_s3dt = p * kappa * E_s3 - alpha * I_s3
dI_s4dt = p * kappa * E_s4 - alpha * I_s4
dI_v1dt = p * kappa * E_v1 - alpha * I_v1
dI_v2dt = p * kappa * E_v2 - alpha * I_v2
dI_v3dt = p * kappa * E_v3 - alpha * I_v3
dI_v4dt = p * kappa * E_v4 - alpha * I_v4
dI_i1dt = p * kappa * E_i1 - alpha * I_i1
dI_i2dt = p * kappa * E_i2 - alpha * I_i2
dI_i3dt = p * kappa * E_i3 - alpha * I_i3
dI_i4dt = p * kappa * E_i4 - alpha * I_i4
dA_s1dt = (1-p) * kappa * E_s1 - eta * A_s1 - epsilon_current1 * A_s1
dA_s2dt = (1-p) * kappa * E_s2 - eta * A_s2 - epsilon_current2 * A_s2
dA_s3dt = (1-p) * kappa * E_s3 - eta * A_s3 - epsilon_current3 * A_s3
dA_s4dt = (1-p) * kappa * E_s4 - eta * A_s4 - epsilon_current4 * A_s4
dA_v1dt = (1-q) * kappa * E_v1 - eta * A_v1 + epsilon_current1 * A_v1 + epsilon_current1 * A_i1
dA_v2dt = (1-q) * kappa * E_v2 - eta * A_v2 + epsilon_current2 * A_v2 + epsilon_current2 * A_i2
dA_v3dt = (1-q) * kappa * E_v3 - eta * A_v3 + epsilon_current3 * A_v3 + epsilon_current3 * A_i3
dA_v4dt = (1-q) * kappa * E_v4 - eta * A_v4 + epsilon_current4 * A_v4 + epsilon_current4 * A_i4
dA_i1dt = (1-l) * kappa * E_i1 - eta * A_i1 - epsilon_current1 * A_i1
dA_i2dt = (1-l) * kappa * E_i2 - eta * A_i2 - epsilon_current2 * A_i2
dA_i3dt = (1-l) * kappa * E_i3 - eta * A_i3 - epsilon_current3 * A_i3
dA_i4dt = (1-l) * kappa * E_i4 - eta * A_i4 - epsilon_current4 * A_i4
dR_s1dt = alpha * I_s1 + eta * A_s1 - epsilon_current1 * R_s1
dR_s2dt = alpha * I_s2 + eta * A_s2 - epsilon_current2 * R_s2
dR_s3dt = alpha * I_s3 + eta * A_s3 - epsilon_current3 * R_s3
dR_s4dt = alpha * I_s4 + eta * A_s4 - epsilon_current4 * R_s4
dR_v1dt = alpha * I_v1 + eta * A_v1 + epsilon_current1 * R_s1 + epsilon_current1 * R_i1
dR_v2dt = alpha * I_v2 + eta * A_v2 + epsilon_current2 * R_s2 + epsilon_current2 * R_i2
dR_v3dt = alpha * I_v3 + eta * A_v3 + epsilon_current3 * R_s3 + epsilon_current3 * R_i3
dR_v4dt = alpha * I_v4 + eta * A_v4 + epsilon_current4 * R_s4 + epsilon_current4 * R_i4
dR_i1dt = alpha * I_i1 + eta * A_i1 - epsilon_current1 * R_i1
dR_i2dt = alpha * I_i2 + eta * A_i2 - epsilon_current2 * R_i2
dR_i3dt = alpha * I_i3 + eta * A_i3 - epsilon_current3 * R_i3
dR_i4dt = alpha * I_i4 + eta * A_i4 - epsilon_current4 * R_i4
dC_s1dt = Lambda1 * S1
dC_s2dt = Lambda2 * S2
dC_s3dt = Lambda3 * S3
dC_s4dt = Lambda4 * S4
dC_v1dt = s_v1 * Lambda1 * S1
dC_v2dt = s_v2 * Lambda2 * S2
dC_v3dt = s_v3 * Lambda3 * S3
dC_v4dt = s_v4 * Lambda4 * S4
dC_i1dt = s_i * Lambda1 * S1
dC_i2dt = s_i * Lambda2 * S2
dC_i3dt = s_i * Lambda3 * S3
dC_i4dt = s_i * Lambda4 * S4
dC_sdt = dC_s1dt + dC_s2dt + dC_s3dt + dC_s4dt
dC_vdt = dC_v1dt + dC_v2dt + dC_v3dt + dC_v4dt
dC_idt = dC_i1dt + dC_i2dt + dC_i3dt + dC_i4dt
dCdt = dC_sdt + dC_vdt + dC_idt
dV_overall1dt = dV1dt + dE_v1dt + dI_v1dt + dA_v1dt + dR_v1dt
dV_overall2dt = dV2dt + dE_v2dt + dI_v2dt + dA_v2dt + dR_v2dt
dV_overall3dt = dV3dt + dE_v3dt + dI_v3dt + dA_v3dt + dR_v3dt
dV_overall4dt = dV4dt + dE_v4dt + dI_v4dt + dA_v4dt + dR_v4dt
return dS1dt, dS2dt, dS3dt, dS4dt, dV1dt, dV2dt, dV3dt, dV4dt, dS_i1dt, dS_i2dt, dS_i3dt, dS_i4dt, dE_s1dt, dE_s2dt, dE_s3dt, dE_s4dt, dE_v1dt, dE_v2dt, dE_v3dt, dE_v3dt, dE_i1dt, dE_i2dt, dE_i3dt, dE_i4dt, dI_s1dt, dI_s2dt, dI_s3dt, dI_s4dt, dI_v1dt, dI_v2dt, dI_v3dt, dI_v4dt, dI_i1dt, dI_i2dt, dI_i3dt, dI_i4dt, dA_s1dt, dA_s2dt, dA_s2dt, dA_s2dt, dA_v1dt, dA_v2dt, dA_v3dt, dA_v4dt, dA_i1dt, dA_i2dt, dA_i3dt, dA_i4dt, dR_s1dt, dR_s2dt, dR_s3dt, dR_s4dt, dR_v1dt, dR_v2dt, dR_v3dt, dR_v4dt, dR_i1dt, dR_i2dt, dR_i3dt, dR_i4dt, dC_s1dt, dC_s2dt, dC_s3dt, dC_s4dt, dC_v1dt, dC_v2dt, dC_v3dt, dC_v4dt, dC_i1dt, dC_i2dt, dC_i3dt, dC_i4dt, dC_sdt, dC_vdt, dC_idt, dCdt, dV_overall1dt, dV_overall2dt, dV_overall3dt, dV_overall4dt 

# Initial conditions vector
y0 = S10, S20, S30, S40, V10, V20, V30, V40, S_i10, S_i20, S_i30, S_i40, E_s10, E_s20, E_s30, E_s40, E_v10, E_v20, E_v30, E_v40, E_i10, E_i20, E_i30, E_i40, I_s10, I_s20, I_s30, I_s40, I_v10, I_v20, I_v30, I_v40, I_i10, I_i20, I_i30, I_i40, A_s10, A_s20, A_s30, A_s40, A_v10, A_v20, A_v30, A_v40, A_i10, A_i20, A_i30, A_i40, R_s10, R_s20, R_s30, R_s40, R_v10, R_v20, R_v30, R_v40, R_i10, R_i20, R_i30, R_i40, C_s10, C_s20, C_s30, C_s40, C_v10, C_v20, C_v30, C_v40, C_i10, C_i20, C_i30, C_i40, C_s0, C_v0, C_i0, C0, V_overall10, V_overall20, V_overall30, V_overall40

# Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
ret = odeint(deriv, y0, t, args=(N, beta11, beta12, beta13, beta14, beta21, beta22, beta23, beta24, beta31, beta32, beta33, beta34, beta41, beta42, beta43, beta44, 
                             kappa, alpha, epsilon1, epsilon2, epsilon3, epsilon4, eta, delta_i, delta_v, delta_a, s_i, s_v1, s_v2, s_v3, s_v4, p, q, l), Dfun=None, col_deriv=0, full_output=0 ,ml=None, mu=None, rtol=None, atol=None, tcrit=None, h0=0.0,hmax=0.0, hmin=0.0, ixpr=0, mxstep=0, mxhnil=0, mxordn=12,mxords=5, printmessg=0, tfirst=False)
S1, S2, S3, S4, V1, V2, V3, V4, S_i1, S_i2, S_i3, S_i4, E_s1, E_s2, E_s3, E_s4, E_v1, E_v2, E_v3, E_v4, E_i1, E_i2, E_i3, E_i4, I_s1, I_s2, I_s3, I_s4, I_v1, I_v2, I_v3, I_v4, I_i1, I_i2, I_i3, I_i4, A_s1, A_s2, A_s3, A_s4,A_v1, A_v2, A_v3, A_v4, A_i1, A_i2, A_i3, A_i4, R_s1, R_s2, R_s3, R_s4, R_v1, R_v2, R_v3, R_v4, R_i1, R_i2, R_i3, R_i4, C_s1, C_s2, C_s3, C_s4, C_v1, C_v2, C_v3, C_v4, C_i1, C_i2, C_i3, C_i4, C_s, C_v, C_i, C, V_overall1, V_overall2, V_overall3, V_overall4 = ret.T

# Plot the data on separate curves. 
# Full dynamics Group 1
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w', figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='#dddddd', axisbelow=True)
ax.plot(t, S1/N, 'blue', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label='Susceptible')
ax.plot(t, V1/N, 'blue', alpha=0.5, lw=2, linestyle = "--", label= 'Vaccinated')
ax.plot(t, S_i1/N, 'blue', alpha=0.5, lw=2, linestyle = "dotted", label= 'Prior Immunity Susceptible')
ax.plot(t, E_s1/N, 'orange', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label= 'Exposed')
ax.plot(t, E_v1/N, 'orange', alpha=0.5, lw=2, linestyle = "--", label= 'Vaccinated Exposed')
ax.plot(t, E_i1/N, 'orange', alpha=0.5, lw=2, linestyle = "dotted", label= 'Prior Immunity Exposed')
ax.plot(t, I_s1/N, 'red', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label= 'Susceptible Infectious')
ax.plot(t, I_v1/N, 'red', alpha=0.5, lw=2, linestyle = "--", label= 'Vaccinated Infectious')
ax.plot(t, I_i1/N, 'red', alpha=0.5, lw=2, linestyle = "dotted", label= 'Prior Immunity Infectious')
ax.plot(t, A_s1/N, 'hotpink', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label= 'Susceptible Asymptomatic')
ax.plot(t, A_v1/N, 'hotpink', alpha=0.5, lw=2, linestyle = "--", label= 'Vaccinated Asymptomatic')
ax.plot(t, A_i1/N, 'hotpink', alpha=0.5, lw=2, linestyle = "dotted", label= 'Prior Immunity Asymptomatic')
ax.plot(t, R_s1/N, 'green', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label= 'Susceptible Recovered')
ax.plot(t, R_v1/N, 'green', alpha=0.5, lw=2, linestyle = "--", label= 'Vaccinated Recovered')
ax.plot(t, R_i1/N, 'green', alpha=0.5, lw=2, linestyle = "dotted", label= 'Prior Immunity Recovered')
ax.set_title ('Dymamics for Age Group 1')
ax.set_xlabel('Time /days')
ax.set_ylabel('Proportion of Population')
ax.set_ylim(0,0.07)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', c='w', lw=2, ls='-')
legend = ax.legend()
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)
```

for spine in ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'):
ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
plt.show()

The error code is:

```
/Users/laurenadams/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py:247: ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this? What does "Run with full_output=1" mean?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I could not reproduce your error due to missing variables. Can you post [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I've just edited the question so it includes my full code. I have just tried changing the full_output so it equals 1 but it gave me a different error